# Files lost by encfs

Tags: files, encryption, data-recovery, data-loss, encfs

I would like to ask you for a help. I recently used the software encfs in my ubuntu 18.04 laptop. I created a new stash using the same software in my desktop. I would like to list the steps....

- I created a new stash (using green plus) in my desktop with same name (Desktop) and a password.
- The newly mounted folder (looked like a drive) hadn't any folder or files.
- Later I removed the stash using the option (red minus) in encfs.
- I thought it would only remove the newly created empty folder.
- Accidentally, I lost my desktop folder (with entire files in it).
- Then home folder acts like the desktop.
- I searched in home for lost files, but found none.
- It didn't affect any files in home folder other than desktop.

Kindly please help me to retrieve my lost files. How can I retrieve them? Thank you.

Comment: What software were you using when you did that (encfs itself does not have a "green plus button")? What version of Ubuntu are you on? It is difficult to understand what you actually did...which folder did you initially try to encrypt, and where did you mount it? What do you mean by "home folder acts like the desktop"?

Comment: @Sebastian, Hi greetings, thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Sebastian, Hi greetings, thank you for the reply. I meant the create or import stash option (a green plus(+) icon). I 'm using ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver. I would like to explain that...    First I tried to create a new stash. Then I gave my "Desktop" folder for encrypting. Then I gave a password. And created a new stash. Then it get mounted on desktop. Later I deleted that stash. But all of my data in my desktop folder has lost. Even, that folder has disappeared. Then now, the folders and files in the home folder are now displaying in desktop, not files in desktop (it had lost). Thank you.

Comment: That sounds weird. I'm not really familiar with encfs, and you still didn't say what application you used, but I would be surprised if it just deleted files. Maybe you somehow specified the folder for the encrypted files to be the same as the original folder? Then that might have overwritten your original folder with the encrypted files.

Comment: @Sebastian Thank you for the comment. I used only encfs. No other apps. Would you mind giving me a solution? Please help.

Comment: If you used only encfs, then what commands did you enter in the terminal? I'm afraid I can't help you anymore than that. You know best what folders you mounted where, and it is still not fully clear to me what you did exactly. In the worst case, assume that your files are lost.

Comment: @Sebastian Hi greetings, I only used the GUI of encfs. I didn't use terminal for that. Actually, I mounted the stash at desktop (the same folder I encrypted). I meant I encrypted desktop folder at desktop itself. Then I deleted that stash and the desktop folder has gone. I used photorec and testdisk for recovery. But I could not find any file I needed. Testdisk didn't show that files during recovery. Actually, I don't know where the files has gone. I am afraid that those files got permanently lost. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I tried installing encfs myself and try to recreate what you did, but there is no GUI installed with it, so I still don't know what you used. In any case, the command line tool does not allow me to put the encrypted and unencrypted folder in the same place. Encfs also requires you to know exactly where you put your encrypted and unencrypted folders, there is no centralized database. Unless you find an `.encfs6.xml` file somewhere in your home directory, I'm afraid your files are gone.

Comment: @Sebastian, Hi greetings, I used a GUI.  For this,  Applications ---> System tools ---> Gnome encfs manager (I'm using metacity environment). Then a icon appear in top panel. Then. "show manager". This is the GUI I have mentioned.

Comment: I cannot find a file like .encfs6.xml in my home folder. Thank you.

Comment: The terminal command for launching appindicator -- gnome-encfs-manager. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere - so you were using Gnome Encfs Manager. Indeed, when selecting ~/Desktop as the "directory to encrypt" (which is already misleading, since it does not encrypt files in that directory), and ~/desktop as the mount point, and then later delete that stash, it will delete ~/Desktop with all that's in it - including the newly encrypted files and all others that were in it before. Did you confirm the warning screen that pops up saying "Yes, I am sure and aware that I could loose my data"?

Comment: @Sebastian Hi greetings, thank you. I confirmed that warning because I thought it will remove only the newly mounted blank drive. I didn't know it would affect my files. Would you mind explaining any ways to recover my lost files? Thank you.

Comment: Well in that case I'm afraid the only way is to try data recovery tools, like you apparently did already. If you don't have a backup, there is nothing else you can do.

Comment: @Sebastian, Hi, thank you for the comment. When I tried that approximately 3,00,000 files had recovered (then I stopped it). And I couldn't find any files that I needed. Regards.